# Aggregating rows for multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have a df that basically looks like this:

```
Id  A    B    C total
3   5    0    1  6
3   4    3    4   11
3   2    1    2    5
4   5    4    3   12
4   3    2    4    9
4   1    1    1    3
```

I want to collapse the rows by Id and get:

```
Id   A    B    C    total
3    11   4    7     22
4    9    7    8   24
```

I was able to do so for one column with:

```
df.grouped<- aggregate(df$A~Id, data=df, FUN="sum")
```

I have many columns (A-Z), so I need some kind of loop. I tried:

```
df.grouped<- aggregate(df[4:51]~Id, data=df, FUN="sum")
names(df.grouped)<-paste(names(df)[4:51])
```

But got:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = df[4:51] ~ Id, data = df) : 
invalid type (list) for variable 'df[4:51]'
```

As you can see, I also want the names in df.grouped to be the same as in df.

Any ideas will be very helpful

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! the first solution works very well.

Comment: @user3315563 To which answer are you referring? Why don't you follow Jaap's above advice? This is the best way to reward people who take time to answer to your questions!

Comment: The first one, with aggregate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the formula method of `aggregate`.  By specifying `.` on the `LHS` of `~`, we select all the columns except the 'Id' column.

```
aggregate(.~Id, df, sum)
#   Id  A B C total
#1  3 11 4 7    22
#2  4  9 7 8    24
```

Or we can also specify the columns without using the formula method

```
aggregate(df[2:ncol(df)],df['Id'], FUN=sum)
#  Id  A B C total
#1  3 11 4 7    22
#2  4  9 7 8    24
```

---

Other options include `dplyr` and `data.table`.

Using `dplyr`, we group by 'Id' and get the `sum` of all columns with `summarise_each`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

Or with `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Id', we loop (`lapply(..`) through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) and get the `sum`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = Id]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `summaryBy` from the `doBy` library:

```
library(doBy)
df.grouped = summaryBy(A + B + C + total ~ Id, data = df, FUN = sum,
    keep.names = TRUE)
```

You may omit `FUN = sum` as it is the default. When calculating length (count), mean, or variance, you can replace is with `FUN = length` or `FUN = mean` and so on.

Since you are also selecting every column of the data frame, you may use `. ~ Id` as a shorthand form.

---

An example that works right out of the box with R:

head(mtcars)
  library(doBy)
  summaryBy(. ~ cyl, data = mtcars, FUN = mean, keep.names = TRUE)

```
cyl      mpg     disp        hp     drat       wt     qsec        vs        am     gear     carb
1   4 26.66364 105.1364  82.63636 4.070909 2.285727 19.13727 0.9090909 0.7272727 4.090909 1.545455
2   6 19.74286 183.3143 122.28571 3.585714 3.117143 17.97714 0.5714286 0.4285714 3.857143 3.428571
3   8 15.10000 353.1000 209.21429 3.229286 3.999214 16.77214 0.0000000 0.1428571 3.285714 3.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

Create df

```
        df <- data.frame(Id = c(3,3,3,4,4,4), 
                         A = c(5,4,2,5,3,1),   
                         B = c(0,3,1,4,2,1),   
                         C = c(1,4,2,3,4,1))
```

library(plyr)

```
req <- ddply( df, .(Id),
           summarise,
           A  = sum(A),
           B  = sum(B),
           C  = sum(C))
```

View(req)